# Python Poetry - update -dev dependencies only to latest

Tags: python-poetry

How do I get Poetry to update `dev` dependencies only to `latest`?

I originally had:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^4.6"
```

But I wanted:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^6.0"
```

I achieved it by manual editing the `pyproject.toml` file.

When I ran `poetry update` it ( brilliantly ) bumped all my normal ( non-dev ) dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

With latest poetry version you should use

`poetry add pytest@latest --group dev`

Answer (score 7):

Since poetry 1.2 supports plugins, and there is a plugin to update all packages at once, you can

- update poetry

```
poetry self update
```

- install up plugin

```bash
poetry self add poetry-plugin-up
```

- up your dev packages to the latest ⬅

```bash
poetry up --only=dev --latest
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the command I wanted:

```
poetry add pytest@latest --dev
```